# install .deb with dpkg in local place in ubuntu

Tags: linux

When I install .deb with dpkg  command in native place in ubuntu,its error is it depends on other .deb,but when I install that .deb,its error is "subprocess installed post-installlation script returned error exit status 1"

Comment: Can you reword this to make it a little clearer?

Comment: which .deb file you want to install ?